# Julia Iterator product and filter

Tags: filter, iterator, julia

I need to find a solution over 3 arrays resolving a + b + c = 15 (or whatever)

so far i'm stuck with the following code:

```matlab
A = 1:10
B = 1:10
C = 1:10

possibilities = Iterators.product(A, B, C)
solutions = Iterators.filter((a, b, c) -> a + b + c == 15, possibilities)
sol = collect(solutions)
for (a, b, c) in sol
   println(a, " ", b, " ", c)
end
```

And I get this error from the compiler:

```
> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
> (::##1#2)(::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}) Closest candidates are:  
> #1(::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any) at /home/cg/root/7729001/main.jl:6 Stacktrace:  [1] start_filter(::##1#2,
> ::Base.Iterators.Prod{UnitRange{Int64},Base.Iterators.Prod2{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}})
> at ./iterators.jl:272  [2] _collect(::UnitRange{Int64},
> ::Base.Iterators.Filter{##1#2,Base.Iterators.Prod{UnitRange{Int64},Base.Iterators.Prod2{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}},
> ::Base.HasEltype, ::Base.SizeUnknown) at ./array.jl:408  [3]
> collect(::Base.Iterators.Filter{##1#2,Base.Iterators.Prod{UnitRange{Int64},Base.Iterators.Prod2{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}})
> at ./array.jl:397 while loading /home/cg/root/7729001/main.jl, in
> expression starting on line 7
```

Maybe you have an idea to solve this or a workaround of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of possibilities are tuples. Treat each as `x` in this code:

```
A = 1:10
B = 1:10
C = 1:10

possibilities = Iterators.product(A, B, C)
# The change is in this line
solutions = Iterators.filter(x -> x[1] + x[2] + x[3] == 15, possibilities)
sol = collect(solutions)
for (a, b, c) in sol
   println(a, " ", b, " ", c)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @JuliaLearner, I appreciate your compliment. I'm also a learner :)

Comment: Yes, and I learned from your answer.  I had posted one that used an array comprehension, but deleted it when I saw how nice and succinct your answer was.  I hope the OP accepts your answer.

Comment: Thank you hesham_EE I didn't thought of that ! I'm still learning the basics in fonctionnal programming.
@JuliaLearner We are all Julia learners here ;)

Answer (score 2):

The other answer correctly diagnoses that you need to work on a tuple, not three arguments.

In Julia 1.0, you can also use [argument destructuring](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Argument-destructuring-1) in the lambda, but the syntax is not as obvious as it could be:

```
Iterators.filter(((a, b, c),) -> a + b + c == 15, possibilities)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I find your expression a bit more readable.